# slf4j don't work in JBOSS when using openJpa module

Tags: jboss7.x, slf4j, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

My EAR application runs fine when i don't use openJpa. Once i use open JPA i get the "SLF4J fail to load class blaaa ". How to configure the openJpa module to use the SL4J which i provide from pom.xml and avoid that error?

I use JBOSS 7.1.1

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>

    <slf4j.version>1.7.3</slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.10</logback.version>
       </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

.......

**openjpa module.xml**

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.openjpa">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="openjpa-2.2.0.jar"/>  
        <resource-root path="openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar"/>  
    </resources>  
        <dependencies>  
            <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>  
            <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
            <module name="javax.validation.api"/>  
            <module name="org.apache.commons.lang"/>  
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>  
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>  
        </dependencies>  
</module>
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**error**

```
10:17:53,854 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

10:17:53,860 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

10:17:53,866 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-4) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

10:17:53,873 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/Logger used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242) [openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254) [openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<clinit>(CacheManager.java:131) [ehcache-ee-2.6.2.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.controller.CacheController.<init>(CacheController.java:39) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:256) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:255) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]

10:17:54,007 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/emyed-whiteboard]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/Logger used in the signature
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/Logger used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242) [openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254) [openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<clinit>(CacheManager.java:131) [ehcache-ee-2.6.2.jar:]
    at com.zreflect.emyed.whiteboard.controller.CacheController.<init>(CacheController.java:39) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:256) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:255) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're probably getting two different versions of sfl4j. Add `<scope>provided</scope>` to your slf4j dependency. The other option would be to provide a [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) to exclude the servers slf4j.

Example jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also make sure you don't have a transitive slf4j dependencies, like sfl4j-jdk14.jar.

Comment: I have also included jboss-deployment-structure.xml and lib has only one version of slf4j. I don't get any error if i don't include openjpa. I think this is problem with openjpa.

Comment: How do you include OpenJPA? Via a module or in the lib directory of your deployment?

Comment: I have included via module

Comment: Is there a way to do withot using moudle? For reason when i remove the openjpa module, the deployment is failing as it is trying to openjpa module.

Comment: You need to exclude slf4j for each submodule that uses it too as it will be added by default to each module of a deployment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-JBossDeploymentStructureFile. It shows how to reference a sub-module. The easiest thing to try would be to not exclude the servers version of slf4j and instead mark it as provided in your POM.

Comment: now i using jboss slf4j but i get this error 19:23:48,389 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

19:23:48,394 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

19:23:48,398 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28929/discussion-between-james-r-perkins-and-user1595858)

Comment: Also need to add openJPA in the exclusion, which fixed the issue

Comment: That seems really odd to me. I don't there is an openJPA module by default.

Comment: Well we had added openJPA as module, otherwise we were having some issue when adding as external jar.